# VSCode UI causes error that terminal doesn't - The hook `black` requires pre-commit version 2.9.2 but version 2.6.0 is installed

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have installed pre-commit in a virtual environment.  The following error pops up whenever I use the commit button / press ctrl + enter in visual studio code.

[image: VS Code - Commit button & error message]

If I use the vs code terminal (WSL) then there is no problem and all the tests including black run:

`pre-commit run --all-files`

or

```
git add wsgi.py
git commit -m "test"
```

There is no problem with the UI if I remove black from the yaml config.

### Versions

- OS: Win11, -> WSL (Ubuntu)
- VS Code 1.72.2
- Python V3.9.5
- pre-commit v2.20.0

### .pre-commit-config.yaml

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.10.0
    hooks:
    -   id: black
```

### Error text

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
[ERROR] The hook `black` requires pre-commit version 2.9.2 but version 2.6.0 is installed.  Perhaps run `pip install --upgrade pre-commit`.
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

you've got multiple installations of `pre-commit` and at least one of them is old!

first you'll want to find all of the `pre-commit`s that are installed on your computer -- it seems that vs code is finding a different one than the one installed in the environment you're running in:

```bash
which -a pre-commit
```

upgrade each of those to the version needed

you can also see which pre-commit is *preferred* by finding the python in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
$ grep 'INSTALL_PYTHON.*=' .git/hooks/pre-commit
INSTALL_PYTHON=/home/asottile/opt/venv/bin/python
```

---

to upgrade, usually run `python -m pip install pre-commit --upgrade` -- where `python` is the executable that `pre-commit` is installed to.  you can usually find that via `head -1 $(which pre-commit)`

---

additionally, you may need to re-synchronize the git hook with the latest version of pre-commit (in case you've moved it or otherwise) -- you can do this by executing the following in your git repo:

```bash
pre-commit install
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: I am having a similar issue but in my case one of the hooks (pytest) cannot find the executable (even though it is installed and language is set to "system") if I try to commit with vscode interface but I can git commit via terminal and `pre-commit run --all-files` completes without issue. Any ideas?